# Should I handle html form validation on front or backend?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, api

Just like the title says.. Should I make sure all values are valid before allowing the form to be submitted to the backend?

Comment: Ideally, both. If it's one or the other, back end.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Front-end validation (javascript) can easily be bypassed. It should only be used to improve the "user experience" - by providing instant feedback. It also reduces the load on the server.

Back-end validation is a MUST. It has to ensure that the data coming in is indeed valid. Additionally, depending on your architecture, you generally re-use your middle-tier business logic amongst multiple components so you need to ensure the rules that are applied are always consistent - regardless of what the front-end logic enforces.

Answer (score 26):

**Frontend validation** can easily be tricked. You should always check the data in the backend. So, while providing frontend validation is nice in concerns of usability, it's totally not neccessary.

**Backend validation** on the other hand is and it's the only way to have sane data.